# Math environment $..$ in tabular works in some cases

Tags: tables, math-mode

I'm new in this, sorry for using noob phrasings (and possibly including too much/little info).  I would think I'm covered from usepackages, but can't get all my math environments in tables to work - only some. I'm providing table examples on what works and what does not.

Hope the relevant info is included:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,oneside,article,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}      
\usepackage{siunitx} %Issue with this package after updating the 29/11-2015. Unsure what the issue is
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{'I am a behaving'}}
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
   \toprule
Electrode reaction & E$^{\circ}$ [V] & Blah blah \\
   \midrule
Au$^{3+}$ + 3e$^-$ $\longrightarrow$ Au & 1.420 \\
Zinc hydroxide     &   &$\beta$-Zn(OH)$_2$   &   \\
Zinc hydroxide     &  & $\gamma$-Zn(OH)$_2$    &  \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{'I don't wanna play (don't worry about my weird content)'}}
\begin{tabular} {llccccc}
   \toprule
Blah & Blah & Blah & \\
   \midrule
[Cr(CO)$_5$]$^{-2}$ & Trigonal bipyramid & -2 \\
Wulﬁngite    &  $\varepsilon$-Zn(OH)$_2$    &  \\
Zinc sulﬁte (h)   &  ZnSO$_3$   $\cdot$ 1/2H$_2$O  &   \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**Comments:**

1. The line `[Cr(CO)$_5$]$^{-2}$ & Trigonal bipyramid & -2 \\`

   Compiling causes "Process started" but can't finish, I am forcing a stop.
2. `Wulﬁngite    &  $\varepsilon$-Zn(OH)$_2$    &  \\`

   and
3. `Zinc sulﬁte (h)   &  ZnSO$_3$   $\cdot$ 1/2H$_2$O  &   \\`

   gives error: `! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 64257 = U+FB01,`

   I thought `amsmath` would fix `$\varepsilon$` issue, but that is not the case.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).  Please do not scatter your question with literal HTML tags, as these tend to break the overall formatting, but use proper [Markdown syntax](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) instead.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to load `amsmath` if you use `mathtools`, the latter loads the former (and is an extension of it).

Comment: Welcome. A hint on how to troubleshoot in LaTeX: make a copy and gradually remove code/usepackages and compile it each time. This can be helpful to find the spot where the error occurs or to reduce information for a MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I'd also look into the `mhchem` package for chemistry typesetting.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- somehow, your update turned double backslashes into triples.  i've removed the extra.

Comment: the `-2` in the last column of the second table really does need to be math; otherwise the `-` will be set as a hyphen, not a minus.  also, `\varepsilon` is available with basic tex, so `amsmath` has no effect.  and as already observed, since this is chemistry, not math, a chemistry package would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was not due to my update.  Please see the edit history for a confirmation.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- just looked, and they do appear on my screen.  the first two show up red, and the third, black, in the "side-by-side markdown" window.  maybe someone's browser is acting up?  (that has happened to me before; using firefox 39.0.)  puzzled.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, I didn't want to give rise to confusion.  I meant, that the original post had three backslashes in the *markdown source* (e.g. `\\\ <br/>`).  I didn't notice that one of these backslashes was used to escape them from HTML and thus didn't edit it out.  The *output* of the original post only shows two backslashes.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- aha!  that didn't occur to me.  thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

After changing the triple backslashes into double and adding `\relax` after the `\midrule` that is followed by `[`, the example compiles.

You should also change the `ﬁ` resulting from copy/paste to `fi`.

I recommend avoiding `utf8x` and favor `utf8`.

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,oneside,article,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}      
\usepackage{siunitx} %Issue with this package after updating the 29/11-2015. Unsure what the issue is
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{'I am a behaving'}}
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
   \toprule
Electrode reaction & E$^{\circ}$ [V] & Blah blah \\
   \midrule
Au$^{3+}$ + 3e$^-$ $\longrightarrow$ Au & 1.420 \\
Zinc hydroxide     &   &$\beta$-Zn(OH)$_2$   &   \\
Zinc hydroxide     &  & $\gamma$-Zn(OH)$_2$    &  \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{'I don't wanna play (don't worry about my weird content)'}}
\begin{tabular} {llccccc}
   \toprule
Blah & Blah & Blah & \\
   \midrule\relax % <---------- HERE
[Cr(CO)$_5$]$^{-2}$ & Trigonal bipyramid & -2 \\
Wulfingite    &  $\varepsilon$-Zn(OH)$_2$    &  \\
Zinc sulfite (h)   &  ZnSO$_3$   $\cdot$ 1/2H$_2$O  &   \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\midrule` accepts an optional argument and it finds the `[` just after it. In these cases, `\relax` is the simplest workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the `mhchem` package if you are doing a lot of chemical typesetting in your document.

Your example would then be:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,oneside,article,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}      
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\mhchemoptions{text-greek=var-default}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{'I am a behaving'}}
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
   \toprule
Electrode reaction & E$^{\circ}$ [V] & Blah blah \\
   \midrule
\ce{Au^{3+} + 3e- -> Au} & \num{1.420} \\
Zinc hydroxide     &  & \ce{\beta-Zn(OH)_2}   &  \\
Zinc hydroxide     &  & \ce{\gamma-Zn(OH)_2}  &  \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{'I don't wanna play (don't worry about my weird content)'}}
\begin{tabular} {llccccc}
   \toprule
Blah & Blah & Blah & \\
   \midrule
\ce{[Cr(CO)_5]^{-2}} & Trigonal bipyramid & \num{-2} \\
Wulfingite    &  \ce{\epsilon-Zn(OH)_2}    &  \\
Zinc sulfite (h)   &  \ce{ZnSO_3  * 1/2H2O}  &   \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This removes the problem with `\midrule` and makes the code a lot easier to write. Since you use `siunitx` I am also put the numbers in a `\num{}` so that they display properly (especially the `-2`).

[image]